# Switch Statement Not Working with Click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, switch-statement

Im really trying to keep my code clean by using the switch statement but it seems its not working some how. I have made an array of objects that have the class `.ClientButtonPic` and if I write

```
var clientButtonNumber = $(".ClientButtonPic");     
$(clientButtonNumber[0]).click(function(){ $(".ClientImages:eq(0)").fadeIn(300); 
$(".ClientImages:eq(1)").fadeOut(300); });
```

It works fine but since I have 6 instances that can be clicked I wanted to use the switch statement. Heres my code:

```
var clientButtonNumber = $(".ClientButtonPic");
$(clientButtonNumber).click(function(){
    switch(this)
     {
case 0:
$(".ClientImages:eq(0)").fadeIn(300);
$(".ClientImages:eq(1)").fadeOut(300);
  break;
case 1:
$(".ClientImages:eq(1)").fadeIn(300);
$(".ClientImages:eq(0)").fadeOut(300);
  break;
default:
  break;
         }
     });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `this` is the DOM object that initiated the event.  It doesn't ever match a number like 0, 1, 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the index of `this`.

```
switch( $(this).index(".ClientButtonPic") )
```